# Using a different heuristic for the A* Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

my professor gave me a simple task to program - at least i thought so. The basics are simple: I have a randomized maze out of n > 20.000 different rooms. I thought "hey great, let's use A* to calculate the optimal route". Now i am encountering the following problem:

The java-program from my professor randomizes the rooms into a large array saving all successor rooms from room X. Example:

Rooms[2427][{42},{289},{2833}] // Room 2427 is next to the rooms 42, 289 and 2833 - those 3 rooms can be entered from room 2427.

A* needs a good heuristic to measure the following costs for each room. Example:

TotalCosts for Room Successor = CompleteCosts for CurrentRoom + Costs from CurrentRoom to Successor + estimated rest costs.

The "estimated rest costs" are the problem. If i had a 2D array i could easily use the air distance from a to b as a basic heuristic cause there will be at least X costs (air distance from a to b). However i can't use that now, because i don't know where the rooms are! They are completely randomized and when i don't know where Room 23878 will be.

Are there any other kinds of heuristics i can use? I cannot just set the estimated rest costs for every open room to 0, can i? Are there better ways?

Thanks!

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think there is an admissible heuristic estimate.

Comment: I thought this for about an hour now... I don't think there is one either. There is just no way to tell something clever like the airdistance out of the way those rooms are saved in java. Tricky thing. So shall i just set the h value (estimated rest costs) to 0?

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to use a general Dijkstra, or Bellman-Ford if there are negative weight edges.

Comment: Yes for a maze there is no heuristic that is of any help making the calculation faster. The next room and the ways beyond can lead all the way back to the starting point. Plain Dijkstra is the way to go. - A* is for maps with some degree of possible overall direction for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using 0 for the heuristic should just work. The 0-heuristic is actually a special case of the A* algorithm, also called the Dijkstra algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no admissible heuristic estimate in this case, i.e. h(x) = 0 in all cases.

However, it seems that the edges of the graph are not weighted. You can simply code BFS, which will run optimally fast (and easy to implement) in O(V+E).